# looks like widechar input from getline in awk

Tags: awk, getline, utf

I'm having trouble with AWK that I've never seen before.

I'm reading in a file, no special chars, and printing it back out.
When I read a text file, it prints out with a NUL between every char.
Reading an HTML file works exactly as expected and prints out what was read in.

Code snippet:
    `while ((getline line < In) > 0) {
       print ":0:", line, ":0:" > "out";`

reads the line "signature1"
and prints

```
":0: xFFxFEsNULiNULgNULnNULaNULtNULuNULrNULeNUL1NUL/r
NUL :0:/r/n"
```

as viewed in Notepad++.

"In" is the input filename.

I assume it is some Language setting on my machine, but I can't find anything.

A second print line, redirected to a file, prints every other line in Chinese.

TL;RD; Complete text of the app:

```
  BEGIN { ProcessFile(); }

  function ProcessFile() {
     In = "default.txt";
     Works = "NoProblem.html";
     Out = "quote.txt";
     RS = "/n";

     while ((getline textLine < In) > 0) {
        print "*0*", textLine, "*0:*" > "out.txt";       
        print textLine > Out; # prints every other line in Chinese  ???
     }
     close(In);
     close(Out);
  }
```

Output of the second print line:
signature1
਍猀椀最渀愀琀甀爀攀㈀ഀഀ

Comment: Your "text file" is UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: @shelter Thx for the pointer in the right direction. I tried to handle this in AWK but couldn't get it sorted. There is an XML extension that might have helped but I didn't try that. Ended up using iconv to process the file. Not satisfactory but got the job done. Thanks again.